# Can I specify a soft mask into a graphics state?

Tags: itext, mask

I'd need to fill in the `SMask` entry of the graphics state dictionary (see Section 4.3.4 of the PDF specification). Do I have any other alternative than to override `PdfGState` for myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved it, it really was a no-brainer. Sorry...

```
public class PdfGStateEx : PdfGState {
  public PdfObject SoftMask {
    set { Put(PdfName.SMASK, value); }
  }
}
```